# Connecting to TSL Redis Cloud using ServiceStack.Redis

Tags: ssl, redis, servicestack, servicestack.redis

I'm attempting to use ServiceStack.Redis to connect to a cloud based Redis instance using SSL Certificates. The ServiceStack documentation provides information on how to connect to an Azure based Redis using SSL, but has no information or examples on how to connect to a non Azure Redis instance.

I've got a pem, crt, and key file but nothing I do with them seems to actually pass them across to the service. I've set ssl=true&sslprotocols=tls12 in the connectionstring which seems like the first step, but beyond that I'm not sure what I should be doing to correctly pass across the certificate for verification

EDIT: Current Code

```
RedisConfig.CertificateSelectionCallback = BuildCertificateSelectionCallback;
RedisConfig.CertificateValidationCallback = Config_CertificateValidation;

var hosts = redCon.Split(',');
var sentinel = new RedisSentinel(hosts, masterName)
{
  RedisManagerFactory = CreateRedisManager,
.....
};
container.Register(c => sentinel.Start());



private static X509Certificate BuildCertificateSelectionCallback(object sender,string targetHost,X509CertificateCollection, X509Certificate remoteCertificate, string[] acceptableIssuers)
{
    return new X509Certificate(@"[filepath]\rl.pfx");
}

private static bool Config_CertificateValidation(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
{
    //Validation not fully fleshed out yet
    if(sslPolicyErrors == SslPolicyErrors.None;)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ServiceStack.Redis uses .NET's [SslStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.security.sslstream.-ctor?view=net-5.0#System_Net_Security_SslStream__ctor_System_IO_Stream_System_Boolean_System_Net_Security_RemoteCertificateValidationCallback_System_Net_Security_LocalCertificateSelectionCallback_) to establish its SSL connection where you can configure its [RemoteCertificateValidationCallback](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.security.remotecertificatevalidationcallback?view=net-5.0) to validate whether to accept the specified certificate for authentication:

```
RedisConfig.CertificateValidationCallback = (object sender,
    X509Certificate certificate,
    X509Chain chain,
    SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) => {
    //...
};
```

And a [LocalCertificateSelectionCallback](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.security.localcertificateselectioncallback?view=net-5.0) to select the local SSL certificate used for authentication:

```
RedisConfig.CertificateSelectionCallback = (object sender,
    string targetHost,
    X509CertificateCollection localCertificates,
    X509Certificate remoteCertificate,
    string[] acceptableIssuers) => {
    //...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, so I just need to set up those functions as part of the Redis Config? 
I had tried putting those in, but the functions were never getting hit. Am I missing a step?
(I've updated the initial question with my code)

Comment: @lasernick If your Sentinel instance requires SSL your host is going to need to be a connection string that [specifies to use ssl](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis#specify-ssl-protocol) and likely your [HostFilter](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis#custom-redis-connection-string) as well. Though I'd try to see if you can get it working without RedisSentinel first (i.e. just RedisManagerPool) then if it works try to configure RedisSentinel

Comment: Ah, I accidentally copied the wrong bit from my code as I have a flag of whether or not to use Sentinel, and it is currently set to false, so that part isn't actually hit right now. And I do have ?ssl=true&sslprotocols=tls12 as part of my connection string. 

Not sure what I did different this time, but my BuildCertificateSelectionCallback function is being hit now. I haven't successfully validated, but I do believe I'm on my way now